# Asterisk 11 on amazon EC2 instance to handle 100 concurrent calls

Tags: amazon-ec2, asterisk

I wanted to know whether asterisk 11 on amazon EC2 would be a good idea so that it can handle more than 100 concurrent calls? If yes then which type of instance will work nicely?
I have a good amount of business logic and application logic as well with the asterisk.
I wanted to know how would be the performance with EC2 instance? is it recommended to use EC2 instance with asterisk?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

amazon ec2 is bad idea for voip.

It have NAT and not perfect timing. Also it not so hi perfomance.

100 calls require instance like c1.xlarge/ m1.xlarge/c3.large - ECU 8+.

On c1.medium asterisk usualy can handle 50-80 calls depend of dialplan and your skill.

Also note, that bandwidth on ec2 is VERY costly.

I not recomend use ec2 instances for asterisk, unless you need have any of following:

- on demand application with failover setup.
- payed per minute/scalable application(for example planned conference service)
- need posibility launch instance on crash and/or other infrastructure already on EC2.

In all other cases much better get 2 dedicated servers and setup failover for thoose servers. You will get much more perfomance for similar cost.

Comment: We tried M1 instance on EC2 for a conference of 14 people. The conference started fine, but the voice of users dropped intermittently while they were speaking. It seemed like as if the call dropped. Asterisk AMI showed that such users are still connected, and our SIP trunk provider also showed that the users are connected.
1) What could be the reason for this?
2) We only saw this once during the US business hours at 4PM MST. We were not able to replicate this problem when we tested after 10PM MST.
What could be the reason?

Comment: Thanks! What would be the cause of loss of audio after starting out fine? Would it be due to missing NAT settings in sip.conf, or would it be due to instance getting overwhelmed? Based on CPU usage it didn't seem like processing power was the issue.

Comment: Please read how vps work. Cause is vps can't grant you realible perfomance. When someone on same node use cpu -you got no cpu, so have issues with voice.

Comment: I dunno...twilio uses aws doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

A successful deployment of Asterisk on Amazon EC2 requires that you enable three critical ports on EC2's firewall. Without them, Asterisk will not work. Thus, the following ports are key to passing RTP packets (for voice) and SIP signaling (for devices, DTMF codes, etc.):

5060 (UDP)

4569 (UDP)

10000-20000 (UDP)

22 (TCP) (You'll need this for SSH access)

Use Eric Hammond's Ubuntu AMI (Amazon Machine Image), ami-ce44a1a7, and the 1000HZ AKI, aki-9b00e5f2. This AKI is important because it is specifically compiled for VoIP applications such as Asterisk. Any AKI (Amazon Kernel Image) other than one set at 1000HZ will produce undesirable results in voice quality and functionality.

TIP: Asterisk 1.4.21.1 is an older, but stable version. Supplement the version number with a newer one if you prefer

Comment: which instance is better for PIAF with g729and asterisk 12.